# positive semi-definiteness by functions

Tags: linear-algebra

$\textbf{My Question:}$
We have a matrix $A$ whose elements are $A_{ij} = \Phi(\max(x_i+x_j-1,0)) $ where we have 
$ 0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ for $ i=1,2,...n$. I need to find the set of functions $\Phi:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ which makes the matrix $A$ positive semi-definite.

$\textbf{What I tried:}$

I started with $n=1$ case. We have
$$
\Phi(\max(2x-1,0)) \geq 0
$$
which implies
$$
\Phi(y) \geq 0 \hspace{4mm}\forall y \in [0,1] 
$$
Then I moved to $n=2$ case. Here we have the following matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
\Phi(\max(2x_1-1,0)) & \Phi(\max(x_1+x_2-1,0)) \\
\Phi(\max(x_1+x_2-1,0)) & \Phi(\max(2x_2-1,0)) \\
\end{pmatrix}
Then I again defined cases:

$\mathbf{Case 1 : x_1 \geq \frac{1}{2}, x_2 \leq \frac{1}{2}, x_1+x_2 \leq 1}$ 
In this case we have the following matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
\Phi(2x_1-1) & \Phi(0) \\
\Phi(0) & \Phi(0) \\
\end{pmatrix}
In order to have a semi-positive definite matrix we need
$$
\Phi(2x_1-1) \geq 0 \\
\Phi(0) \leq \Phi(2x_1-1)
$$

$\mathbf{Case 2 : x_1 \geq \frac{1}{2}, x_2 \leq \frac{1}{2}, x_1+x_2 \geq 1}$
In this case we have the following matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
\Phi(2x_1-1) & \Phi(x_1+x_2-1) \\
\Phi(x_1+x_2-1) & \Phi(0) \\
\end{pmatrix}
In order to have a semi-positive definite matrix we need
$$
\Phi(2x_1-1) \geq 0 \\
\Phi(2x_1-1) \Phi(0) - \Phi(x_1+x_2-1)^2 \geq 0
$$

$\mathbf{Case 3 : x_1 \geq \frac{1}{2}, x_2 \geq \frac{1}{2}, x_1+x_2 \geq 1}$
In this case we have the following matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
\Phi(2x_1-1) & \Phi(x_1+x_2-1) \\
\Phi(x_1+x_2-1) & \Phi(2x_2-1) \\
\end{pmatrix}
In order to have a semi-positive definite matrix we need
$$
\Phi(2x_1-1) \geq 0 \\
\Phi(2x_1-1) \Phi(2x_2-1) - \Phi(x_1+x_2-1)^2 \geq 0
$$

So far I concluded that $\Phi$ should be non-negative. However, I do not understand what to conclude from Case 2 and Case 3. How can I proceed?

Comment: Just a comment: did you try making your matrix strictly diagonally dominant? That would ensure positive definiteness.

Comment: A quick remark about case 1: how do you conclude that $\Phi$ is non-decreasing?

Comment: @julien: Because we have $\Phi(0) \leq \Phi(2x-1)$ for each $x \in [1/2,1]$. We also know that the domain of $\Phi$ is [0,1]

Comment: This does not prove that $\Phi$ is non-decreasing. Only that it is greater or equal to $\Phi(0)$. If you had $\Phi(0)\geq 0$, this would prove that $\Phi$ is nonnegative. Nothing more.

Comment: @julien: Thanks, you are right.

Comment: @Dominique: Thanks, I'll check that

Comment: You've already asked a similar question earlier. So I am just wondering. Where do these questions come from? A book?